# Not able to find Service Analytics Admin permission set

Tags: permissions, field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I am trying to create App in Einstein with **Field Service Analytics** template.

To do the above I am following [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_help_setup_service_wave_permissions.htm&type=5#bi_help_setup_service_wave_permissions).

I need to provide below permission sets to the **Integration User**:

- Service Analytics Admin
- Service Analytics User

But I am not able to find these two permission sets.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Do you have the Einstein Analytics licenses? This is probably why you don't see the permission sets I was having the same problem while following that article.
On my side, I was looking at those permission set, and turns out I'm not even able to create permission set with those licenses and that's because I don't have the required licenses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Service Analytics Admin** and **Service Analytics User** are type of licenses for the permission sets.

We can find the permission sets with the above licenses in *Setup*->*Users*->*Permission Sets*:

[image]